# Prove divergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

The question is to prove that the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{4\log n\log\log n}$$
diverges.

I tried using the Cauchy condensation test but could not prove it.

Comment: The series should start with $n=3.$

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By comparison:
$$\log n \log \log n \leq n \log n$$
for all sufficiently big $n$, so
$
\sum_n \frac{1}{\log n \log \log n}
$
diverges by comparison with $
\sum_n \frac{1}{n \log n}
$. (Which itself diverges by e.g. the integral test, noting that $\int \frac{dx}{x \log x } = \log\log x$.)

Comment: The test series is one of *Bertrand's series* anyway, known to diverge.

Comment: @Bernard Indeed. That's the usual proof, at least the one I learned when proving the result on Bertrand series (the border case $\sum_n \frac{1}{n\log n}$: worth repeating now and then, in case the OP is not familiar with it).

Comment: I agree the argument is correct. I just meant everyone should know (and use) the results on Bertrand's series.

Comment: @Bernard Well. I agree, but the result on Bertrand series appears to be less known in the US and possibly the UK than it is in at least France. As an indication of that, the [French Wikipedia page on Bertrand series](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9rie_de_Bertrand) has no English translation. In any case, that's only anecdotal for this particular answer, since it's only used in the very last step (and one could have chosen to compare with the Harmonic series instead, for instance.)

Answer (score 2):

For large $n,$

$$\ln n\cdot \ln \ln n < (\ln n)^2 < (\sqrt n)^2 =n.$$

Taking reciprocals and comparing to the harmonic series then shows our series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

$\log{\log{2^n}}=\log{n}+\log{\log{2}}$

$\log{2^n}=n\log{2}$

You can use Cauchy's condensation theorem:

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{2^n}{4n\log{n}\log{2}+n\log{2}\log{\log{2}}}$$

This series clrearly diverges.

Note that:

> $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{2^n}{4n\log{n}\log{2}+n\log{2}\log{\log{2}}}\geq \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{2^n}{8n\log{n}\log{2}}\geq \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^n}{8n^2 \log{2}}$$